# Why huge icon 512 x 512 still rendering as pixelate on iPhone?

Tags: ios, png, vector-graphics

I'm on **Swift 4.2** - I have an icon `512 x 512` with resolution `300` ppi.

[image]

I imported into my asset folder, moved it to the `2x` section, and select `preserve vector data`

[image]

In the phone, I notice it rendering as wrinkle/pixelate in a very weird way.

[image]

When I zoom I see this

[image]

Am I do anything wrong? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is pixelated? Maybe I don't have eagle eyes but I feel right when seeing the icon on the iPhone. If you take simulator screenshot then zoom out, eventually all icons will look pixelated like that. It's worth to mention that `Preserve vector data` should go with a PDF and `Single Scale`, otherwise it doesn't do anything. If this is PNG, then you should have @1x, @2x and @3x image.

Comment: This is the exact image that I have in my asset folder : https://i.imgur.com/wGYkscO.png

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure about below points.

1) Add a PDF image to the asset catalog and be sure to tick Preserve Vector Data as before:

[image]

2) When adding the image view or button to the Storyboard make sure to tick Adjusts Image Size:

[image]

3) If adding the image view in code:

```
imageView.adjustsImageSizeForAccessibilityContentSizeCategory = true
```

**Please refer:**
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-9-vector-images/

Comment: This is the exact image that I have in my asset folder : https://i.imgur.com/wGYkscO.png